# Update Problem, Error: is not a package or launch file name

Tags: ros, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
everything was OK before I did update.
After update of ROS packages the ROS Groovy not work or give me the following message:

```
[move_monsun] is not a package or launch file name when I use the lanch file
```

---

```
roslaunch move_monsun move_monsun.launch
<launch>
    <group ns="monsun"> 
      <node pkg="move_monsun" name="PID_Move" type="move_monsun_node" output="screen">
    <param name="k_p" value="1.0" type="double"/>
    <param name="k_i" value="0.0" />
    <param name="k_d" value="0.0" />
    <param name="k_pl" value="1.0" type="double"/>
    <param name="k_il" value="0.0" />
    <param name="k_dl" value="0.0" />
    <param name="i_max" value="0.0" />
    <param name="output_min" value="-60.0" />
    <param name="output_max" value="60.0" />
    <param name="output_minl" value="-40.0" />
    <param name="output_maxl" value="40.0" />
     </node>
    </group>
</launch>
```

I am sure, I don't make any change in path of ros_workspace. I am run for the same packages before the update and they work  and after the update don't work.
I'm sure I did not do to change anything in the my files only I've update for my ROS_packages.
I tred rosmake agin for the same packges and I get the follwing:

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                                                                        
[ rosmake ] No package or stack specified.  And current directory 'move_monsun' is not a package name or stack name.                   
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: []                                                                                                 
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/amory/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130703-172136                                               
[ rosmake ] Expanded args [] to:
[]                                                                                                    
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
```

In my .bashrc there the path of ROS

```
source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
export ROS_WORKSPACE=~/ros_workspace
```

And roscd is working.
Any ideas
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66515/update-problem,-error:-is-not-a-package-or-launch-file-name/) by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-03

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-10**:
Is it still not working ? Did you try to reinstall everything from scratch ?

**Comment by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on 2013-07-11**:
Yes, I install fresh ROS and I get the same problem.May be the problem in path of ROS but I written as above.

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-11**:
Did you check rosdep version ? Command line is rosdep --version I had the same kind of problems as yours with a new ROS install and it apparently came from the fact that rosdep wasn't up to date.

**Comment by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on 2013-07-11**:
( 0.10.21 version)

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-11**:
Ok, rosdep is ok then. But I do not think you have to add ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and ROS_WORKSPACE to your .bashrc since some other files are called from setup.bash to set them up. Plus, the path you set for ROS_PACKAGE_PATH seems wrong to me because it doesn't lead to stacks and share folders.

**Comment by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on 2013-07-11**:
My path ros_workspace is /home/amory/ros_workspace

**Comment by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on 2013-07-11**:
And in .bashrc is the follwing :source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash
export ROS_WORKSPACE=~/ros_workspace
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. What is wrong ?

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-12**:
My mistake. I mixed up ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and ROS_WORKSPACE. It doesn't seem to come from your path definition. Seems like your problem is somewhere deeper in your ROS system. Maybe some tool is broken ?

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-07-21**:
Please stop 'updating' your question to push it to the top!

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-07-21**:
Obviously, the aren't any ideas. Be more precise, post the exact directory layout with important files, place a echo $ROS.. right with the roslaunch etc. You are using a rosbuild package, right? Do you have a CATKIN_IGNORE file in your package?

**Comment by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on 2013-07-21**:
/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks:/home/amory/ros_workspace

**Comment by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on 2013-07-21**:
yes I ues rosbuild package and I don't have a CATKIN_IGNORE file in my package

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-07-21**:
Uhm, with the export lines you posted the path could not result to what you posted above. Please ensure your question. - And run roswtf from inside your package.

**Comment by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on 2013-07-21**:
it work finr,
Package: move_monsun
Static checks summary:

Found 2 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING You are missing core ROS Python modules: bloom -- rosrelease --
WARNING You are missing Debian packages for core ROS Python modules: bloom (python-bloom) -- rosrelease (python-rosrelease) --

================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules

Online checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:

- /rosout:

  - /rosout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This could be related to [ros-infrastructure/rospkg/issues/39](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rospkg/issues/39).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2013-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-07-08**:
I could confirm that. With the update my rosbuild package I had used make eclipse-project with broke launching and removing CATKIN_IGNORE helped.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

what kind of build system do you use?
If you use catkin, did you source the setup file?

Greetz
Sonne

---

Originally posted by [Sonne](https://answers.ros.org/users/5074/sonne/) with karma: 76 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on 2013-07-03**:
I use rosmake and ROS Groovy with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Ubuntu 13.04 and I get the same problem for both version of Ubunto

**Comment by [Sonne](https://answers.ros.org/users/5074/sonne/) on 2013-07-03**:
Ok, I thought it could be the same problem like I have. But I use catkin. Have you tried to build your package again?

**Comment by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on 2013-07-03**:
I just have tred and I get the following :[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] No package or stack specified.  And current directory 'move_monsun' is not a package name or stack name.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to include the move_monsun directory in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on 2013-07-03**:
but move_monsun is a package where in the ros_workspace ~/ros_workspace/move_monsun

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-03**:
is your ros_workspace still in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH ?

**Comment by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on 2013-07-03**:
yes, I am sure

**Comment by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on 2013-07-03**:
source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
export ROS_WORKSPACE=~/ros_workspace

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-08**:
Are all you packages concerned by this problem ? I am dealing with a quite similar issue with a new ROS installation.

**Comment by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on 2013-07-09**:
Yes, all  packages.

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-09**:
Ok, then we might be struggling with the same troubles. I am trying to reinstall from scratch in order to understand what went wrong. I'll keep you up

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-09**:
Ok, here's my question : http://answers.ros.org/question/66797/ros-installation-failed I finally got it working. I hope the answer will help you

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Taken from the wiki

```
For a package to be considered a catkin package it must meet a few requirements:

The package must contain a catkin compliant package.xml file
That package.xml file provides meta information about the package
The package must contain a CMakeLists.txt which uses catkin
The exception to this rule is that catkin metapackages do not have a CMakeLists.txt file
There can be no more than one package in each folder
This means no nested packages nor multiple packages sharing the same directory
```

I think you might be missing some files. I had a similar problem once and it was solved through this. Check if you have all these files and follow the following tutorial correctly

```
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage
```

If it still does not work, you might have to change the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

---

Originally posted by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) with karma: 729 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2013-07-18**:
Just to be clear: while certainly helpful in making sure the OP has the proper files for a catkin package, this particular error was caused by a problem in `ros/mk` and `catkin`. See [ros/issues/20](https://github.com/ros/ros/issues/20) for more information.